# AlarmManager sometimes not firing

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

Strange issue, my app has tens of thousands of users, for most of them this works perfectly. Some, let's say 5%, experience issue that causes reminders to not be fired.

I've put logging on the scheduling mechanism, including the scheduled timestamp, so I know that the reminder was scheduled, but it AlarmReceiver wasn't called.

Why would AlarmManager sometimes not fire?

ReminderLogic.java -

```
public class ReminderLogic {

    public static void schedule() {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        int timeMillis = ... // some calculation

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) 
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeMillis, alarmIntent);
        else 
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeMillis, alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java -

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }   
}
```

AlarmService.java -

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {
    private final static String TAG = "AlarmService";

    public AlarmService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        ReminderLogic.schedule();

        AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

BootReceiver.java -

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ReminderLogic.schedule();
    }

}
```

PackageReplaceReceiver.java -

```
public class PackageReplaceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "BootReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ReminderLogic.schedule();
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml -

```
    <service android:name=".reminders.AlarmService" />
    <receiver android:name=".reminders.AlarmReceiver" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".reminders.BootReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".reminders.PackageReplaceReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: possibly, these 5% have any taskManager that kills Your app before alarm will fire.For example Huawei devices have their own energy saver, the app must be protected to be not killed.....

Comment: Oh, very interesting, indeed some of the users complaining had Huawei. Any idea how to protect an app from being killed?

Comment: programmatically not, sorry. I also have searched for that case but there is no possibility without root. The only way is too inform the users about.

Comment: Especially for whatsApp I can see that this is automatically protected in my Huawei, but I think this is implemented inside the Energy Manager itself.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to verify this with my customers.